# What is the result of the integration by parts of $\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n}\, v \, d\Omega$?

Tags: integration, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n}\, v \, d\Omega,$$

where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded domain with Lipschitz continuous and piecewise smooth boundary $\Gamma:=\partial \Omega$, $u, v \in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\mathbb{n}$ is the unit normal vector.
In others words, is it possible to apply the Divergence theorem to this integral? What is the solution?

Comment: Are you sure about the integral you mentioned? The normal derivative $\nabla u\cdot n$ is defined on the boundary. Green's theorem tells you that

Comment: Yes. I obtained $-\int_{\Omega} \nabla^2 u v= \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v -\int_{\Gamma} \nabla u \cdot \mathbb{n} v$. Then, I need to integrate by parts $\int_{\Gamma} \nabla u\cdot \mathbb{n} v$ again to obatin something in the boundary of $\Gamma$. But I did not find any results on that.

Comment: How is your normal vector defined? The normal vector is normal to what?

Comment: $\mathbf{n}$ stands for the exterior unit normal vector field.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your integral? The normal derivative is defined on the boundary. Green's theorem would give you (with some extra regularity):
$$
\int_{\Gamma} (\nabla u \cdot n) v = \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v - \int_{\Omega} \Delta u v.
$$

Comment: Unfortunately, the integral is in $\Omega$. I'd like to know if it is possible to integrate by part the following equation
$\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \mathbb{n} \, v \, d\Omega$.

Comment: How do you even compute $\nabla u \cdot n$ in $\Omega$? Can you provide some context or source for this question? I beleive there is something wrong woith the question. @Neo

Comment: By integration by parts I obtained $-\int_{\Omega} \nabla^2 u v= \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v -\int_{\Gamma} \nabla u \cdot \mathbb{n} v$. Then, I need to integrate by parts $\int_{\Gamma} \nabla u\cdot \mathbb{n} v$ again to obatin something in the boundary of $\Gamma$. But I did not find any results on that.

Comment: @Neo The boundary of $\Gamma$ is $\Gamma$...

Comment: No, I am looking for something in a line of $\Gamma$. My guess is something $\int_{\Gamma} = \int_{C}$.

Comment: What do you mean by a line in $\Gamma$? A subset of $\Gamma$ where you have some special boundary conditions? You started by saying that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, so $\Gamma$ is already a line...

Comment: I think you have reached the end of the line... The integral over $\Gamma$ is usually computed using neumann boundary conditions of $u$ ( if this comes from some pde) or by considering $v$ to be in some subspace of $H^1$.

Comment: In my question the integral is in $\Omega$, which is a surface. And I would like to know the integration by parts of this integral.

Comment: Ok, I finally understand what you want to compute... You should correct your initial post. Although $\Omega$ may be homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is not true that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. So your initial problem is on a volume $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, you applied integration by parts obtaing a boundary term (on the surface $\Omega = \partial V$) and now you want to apply a new integration by parts to reduce the calculation to a line integral?

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Do you know the answer to my question?